# Tensorflow Serving in Amazon SageMaker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, amazon-sagemaker

I am facing an issue with serving tensorflow models on AWS SageMaker. I have trained the model outside of the SageMaker environment, now I have a savedmodel.pb file and I need to deploy it on a SageMaker endpoint. So I simply zipped the model file and uploaded it to an S3 bucket.
Now, when trying to create an endpoint, I get the following error in my Cloudwatch log:

> tensorflow_serving/sources/storage_path/file_system_storage_path_source.cc:369]
>   FileSystemStoragePathSource encountered a file-system access error:
>   Could not find base path /opt/ml/model/export/Servo for servable
>   generic_model

I believe SageMaker is looking for the tar.gz to follow a particular directory structure. However, all I have is a .pb file.

Comment: Can you verify that you also have a non-empty `variables` folder next to your `.pb` file?

Comment: The variables folder is empty.

Comment: Not sure, but the error suggests that you are pointing to the wrong path when setting up the server or so.

Comment: @sdcbr does the tar.gz file need to follow any particular directory structure? Currently my tar.gz file only has the pb file (in root)

Comment: @VedantBajaj did you get it to work? Do you mind sharing how? I am stuck on this too.

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow Serving expects the following folder structure:

*export/Servo/{version_number}* where the version number is any valid positive number.

SageMaker expects the same directory format of TFS, there is a GH issue about this https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/issues/599

Comment: Hi, I have kept my `saved_model.pb` file inside `export/Servo/1` but I am still facing this error. Some help please?